# Solr: getting error on url field while updating

Tags: python, python-2.7, solr, urllib2

I am trying to update url fields of my Solr documents but i am getting below error

> HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

I think it is because of a url field

```
image_new_path = https://aaa.com/bbb/posts/post_fta6cueqq1497926075564.jpeg
req = urllib2.Request(url=solrPath + '/update/json?commit=true', data='[{"id":"' + docs['id'] + '","image":{"set":'+image_new_path+'}}]')
```

Is there are some special character which i have to change? If yes which one and how?

Solr error:

```
RequestHandlerBase

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot parse provided JSON: Expected ',&#8203;' or '}': char=:,&#8203;position=41 BEFORE='[{"id":"189",&#8203;"image":{"set":https:' AFTER='//aaa.com/bbb/user'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is ":" i have to add '\' before ':' to make it work. So now image path becomes

```
https\://aaa/bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `""` around your `image_new_path` value, you can fix this by adding `""` around it:

```
.. {"set":"'+image_new_path+'"}}
```

.. but you should not write JSON manually by concatenating values yourself, as you'll have to take care of following all of JSON's rules when it comes to escaping etc.

Use the built-in support in python for json in the `json` module instead:

```
import json

..

.. data=json.dumps([{'id': docs['id'], 'image': {'set': image_new_path}}])
```

Or maybe even better, use a Solr library such as [pysolr](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr) or [mysolr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysolr/).